# Redirect to template not working after Foundation Framework installation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, zurb-foundation, partial

On my local host after having rails create a new object in the database (through a controller) I used to have my app render a template (if @object.save returns true). After installing zurb foundation the template doesn't show and neither does my flash message, the new object `Investor` is also not being created at all. The logs doesn't make much sense to me. Any help here?

generated html form

```
<form div class="small-6 large-centered columns">
    <fieldset>
        <legend> Enter your best details</legend>
<form class="new_investor" id="new_investor" action="/investors" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" /><input type="hidden" name="authenticity_token" value="Ipbkx9oO1mWplLMXhCZA8q7nbgHr4jm9Y7BHHzLryV2va0qHzY1W04ifxu2sPHm6Iz0r7+7ZPwMsyE8sfWpiLg==" />



    <label for="investor_name">Name</label>
    <input placeholder="John Doe" type="text" name="investor[name]" id="investor_name" /> </br>

    <label for="investor_email">Email</label>
    <input placeholder="you@example.com" type="text" name="investor[email]" id="investor_email" /></br>

    <label for="investor_country">Country</label>
    <input type="text" name="investor[country]" id="investor_country" /></br>

    <label for="investor_phone">Phone</label>
    <input placeholder="+48000000" type="text" name="investor[phone]" id="investor_phone" /></br>

    <input type="submit" name="commit" value="I&#39;m interested!" class="button radius" />
</form> </fieldset>
<form>
```

routes

```
siaw ~/Desktop/ps/forex $ rake routes
              Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                     Controller#Action
                root GET    /                               investors#index
static_pages_welcome GET    /static_pages/welcome(.:format) redirect(301, static_pages/welcome.html)
           investors GET    /investors(.:format)            investors#index
                     POST   /investors(.:format)            investors#create
        new_investor GET    /investors/new(.:format)        investors#new
       edit_investor GET    /investors/:id/edit(.:format)   investors#edit
            investor GET    /investors/:id(.:format)        investors#show
                     PATCH  /investors/:id(.:format)        investors#update
                     PUT    /investors/:id(.:format)        investors#update
                     DELETE /investors/:id(.:format)        investors#destroy
```

new.html.erb

```
<form div class="small-6 large-centered columns">
    <fieldset>
        <legend> Enter your best details</legend>
<%= form_for(@investor) do |f| %>

 <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>

    <%= f.label :name %>
    <%= f.text_field :name, :placeholder => "John Doe" %> </br>

    <%= f.label :email %>
    <%= f.text_field :email, :placeholder => "you@example.com" %></br>

    <%= f.label :country %>
    <%= f.text_field :country %></br>

    <%= f.label :phone %>
    <%= f.text_field :phone, :placeholder => "+48000000000" %></br>

    <%= f.submit "I'm interested!", :class => 'button radius' %>
<% end %>
    </fieldset>
<form>
```

routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  root 'investors#index'
  get '/static_pages/welcome', :to => redirect('static_pages/welcome.html')

  resources :investors

end
```

inverstors_controller.rb

```
class InvestorsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @investor = Investor.first
  end

  def show
    @investor = Investor.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @investor = Investor.new
  end

  def create
    @investor = Investor.new(user_params)
    if @investor.save
        flash[:success] = "Welcome, you're now on your way to success!"
        redirect_to "static_pages/welcome"
      InvestorMailer.welcome_email(@investor).deliver_now
    else
        render 'new'
    end
  end

  def update
    if @investor.update_attributes(user_params)
        flash[:success] = "Updated"
    else
        render 'edit'
    end
  end

  private

    def user_params
      params.require(:investor).permit(:name, :email, :country,
                                   :phone)
    end
end
```

application.html.erb

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

    <title><%= content_for?(:title) ? yield(:title) : "Smart Investor Club" %></title>

    <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application" %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag "vendor/modernizr" %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag "application", 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="row">
  <% flash.each do |name, msg| %>
    <% if msg.is_a?(String) %>
      <%= content_tag :div, msg, class: "alert-box #{name} radius" %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
</div>


    <%= yield %>

  </body>
</html>
```

_error_messages.html.erb

```
<% if object.errors.any? %>
  <div>
    <div>
      The form contains <%= pluralize(object.errors.count, "error") %>.
    </div>
    <ul>
    <% object.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
      <li data-alert class="alert-box warning round"><%= msg %></li>
    <% end %>
    </ul>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

logs

```
Started GET "/" for ::1 at 2015-06-12 02:17:12 +0200
  ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations".* FROM "schema_migrations"
Processing by InvestorsController#index as HTML
  Investor Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "investors".* FROM "investors"  ORDER BY "investors"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
   (0.3ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "investors"
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "investors"
  Rendered investors/index.html.erb within layouts/application (2.6ms)
Completed 200 OK in 382ms (Views: 359.3ms | ActiveRecord: 2.9ms)


Started GET "/assets/foundation_and_overrides.self-464f93cbdaa7634d29f2bb979d2132db759337852a741d1de08d9aa3b85ed35e.css?body=1" for ::1 at 2015-06-12 02:17:13 +0200


Started GET "/assets/investor.self-e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855.css?body=1" for ::1 at 2015-06-12 02:17:13 +0200


Started GET "/assets/application.self-489c3e007974fbfaa496637ac1204061ef9d39f4dd29f1f5d1eae0ed61b80625.css?body=1" for ::1 at 2015-06-12 02:17:13 +0200


Started GET "/assets/vendor/modernizr.self-74da3245def7569da28115667be6a85a2ad97464abe707c9829c46d8975597bc.js?body=1" for ::1 at 2015-06-12 02:17:13 +0200


Started GET "/assets/jquery.self-d03a5518f45df77341bdbe6201ba3bfa547ebba8ed64f0ea56bfa5f96ea7c074.js?body=1" for ::1 at 2015-06-12 02:17:13 +0200


Started GET "/assets/foundation/foundation.self-ee5396739ce46beb039f26ea629172a74143752d74f703c6c3b219fc52aecf73.js?body=1" for ::1 at 2015-06-12 02:17:13 +0200


Started GET "/assets/jquery_ujs.self-8e98a7a072a6cee1372d19fff9ff3e6aa1e39a37d89d6f06861637d061113ee7.js?body=1" for ::1 at 2015-06-12 02:17:13 +0200


Started GET "/assets/foundation/foundation.abide.self-f8b56c707a79139807305a5f7efc2aaa0848f0c677abcc056496f507e0192b79.js?body=1" for ::1 at 2015-06-12 02:17:13 +0200


Started GET "/assets/foundation/foundation.accordion.self-d55abdcb0a7a29512be2f31f63d418cc8cc4505a0a3c71946d25484b0a0b3f4e.js?body=1" for ::1 at 2015-06-12 02:17:13 +0200


Started GET "/assets/foundation/foundation.alert.self-fbde7afb61e8ffd8ab9b717f0bed1e58cb9e0144a25cc773fea634d5554f62cd.js?body=1" for ::1 at 2015-06-12 02:17:13 +0200


Started GET "/assets/foundation/foundation.clearing.self-54610737b435a97590fcb176848c3c7a44c4d55d369894260fa7c28c97a70a23.js?body=1" for ::1 at 2015-06-12 02:17:13 +0200


Started GET "/assets/foundation/foundation.dropdown.self-c9ee29909e266373e5e814a73fc6ea062245ddd29466d35d232448f73350d78a.js?body=1" for ::1 at 2015-06-12 02:17:13 +0200


Started GET "/assets/foundation/foundation.equalizer.self-7aa743bf4660deb2fb2f601c112806a1703c430067531da3f41e4afffe19fee9.js?body=1" for ::1 at 2015-06-12 02:17:13 +0200


Started GET "/assets/foundation/foundation.interchange.self-dad8415355087cb21a16fa44bac20d602344d52de5aca9e588e3588fce5dd5a7.js?body=1" for ::1 at 2015-06-12 02:17:13 +0200


Started GET "/assets/foundation/foundation.joyride.self-0a5271728699423f583dd5b3b8a11bfe0dc9fb5044446bcf3218ef8ca906a82d.js?body=1" for ::1 at 2015-06-12 02:17:13 +0200


Started GET "/assets/foundation/foundation.magellan.self-a50193f172f11e57b373c3001072ba2d6b34b857ab251e9ded30af5242855687.js?body=1" for ::1 at 2015-06-12 02:17:13 +0200


Started GET "/assets/foundation/foundation.offcanvas.self-75bffd0c7f4f0d2992ab95f0cc6959282ebb5807da70123d40c01d76e230ec88.js?body=1" for ::1 at 2015-06-12 02:17:13 +0200


Started GET "/assets/foundation/foundation.orbit.self-f8d30eb1717c874db26723f9e07901ec0a325d59263f1404ee83a616bb597ad2.js?body=1" for ::1 at 2015-06-12 02:17:13 +0200


Started GET "/assets/foundation/foundation.reveal.self-95f01feb3e25e47b58b78da0021ae2fffafdee70846682067c180e0e10f7b095.js?body=1" for ::1 at 2015-06-12 02:17:13 +0200


Started GET "/assets/foundation/foundation.slider.self-8911a7352cb577b6b7973b0734d57d2b624c79286558ffa36fcac0c29b2d0bee.js?body=1" for ::1 at 2015-06-12 02:17:13 +0200


Started GET "/assets/foundation/foundation.tab.self-9bf6791513d1b20e213bb1aee3df0bc17128c7e18421258dc68a2a4ccabe1647.js?body=1" for ::1 at 2015-06-12 02:17:13 +0200


Started GET "/assets/foundation/foundation.tooltip.self-834156796c253580629cfffc720bdc3d191b1e5a5a6ddbc1102ecd08c876516c.js?body=1" for ::1 at 2015-06-12 02:17:13 +0200


Started GET "/assets/foundation/foundation.topbar.self-105416f061562f07c6a0a8057d68282fdc1eeb5dc306713fcae6c9a53001fc55.js?body=1" for ::1 at 2015-06-12 02:17:13 +0200


Started GET "/assets/foundation.self-abe4ee7a105042f73b12b1f1a28788522d2f253445a475a94ab4d6e1f7b0ec52.js?body=1" for ::1 at 2015-06-12 02:17:13 +0200


Started GET "/assets/turbolinks.self-c37727e9bd6b2735da5c311aa83fead54ed0be6cc8bd9a65309e9c5abe2cbfff.js?body=1" for ::1 at 2015-06-12 02:17:13 +0200


Started GET "/assets/investor.self-877aef30ae1b040ab8a3aba4e3e309a11d7f2612f44dde450b5c157aa5f95c05.js?body=1" for ::1 at 2015-06-12 02:17:13 +0200


Started GET "/assets/application.self-79a300d240bbf145c9af961805bc87f18e9f73bd1cda275895295c80d8552d3f.js?body=1" for ::1 at 2015-06-12 02:17:13 +0200


Started GET "/investors/new" for ::1 at 2015-06-12 02:17:16 +0200
Processing by InvestorsController#new as HTML
  Rendered shared/_error_messages.html.erb (4.2ms)
  Rendered investors/new.html.erb within layouts/application (20.6ms)
Completed 200 OK in 113ms (Views: 111.7ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)


Started GET "/investors/new" for ::1 at 2015-06-12 02:18:04 +0200
Processing by InvestorsController#new as HTML
  Rendered shared/_error_messages.html.erb (0.0ms)
  Rendered investors/new.html.erb within layouts/application (2.7ms)
Completed 200 OK in 89ms (Views: 88.6ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)


Started GET "/investors/new?utf8=%E2%9C%93&authenticity_token=qgXmHuloO7rKfYIUXFH5PVjsLDjpYcNDsX6gIff71a4n%2BEhe%2Fuu7DOt29%2B50S8B11TZp1uxaxf3%2BBqgSuHp%2B3Q%3D%3D&investor%5Bname%5D=Emmanuel&investor%5Bemail%5D=lalapnt%40yahoo.com&investor%5Bcountry%5D=Poland&investor%5Bphone%5D=000000000&commit=I%27m+interested%21" for ::1 at 2015-06-12 02:18:16 +0200
Processing by InvestorsController#new as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"qgXmHuloO7rKfYIUXFH5PVjsLDjpYcNDsX6gIff71a4n+Ehe/uu7DOt29+50S8B11TZp1uxaxf3+BqgSuHp+3Q==", "investor"=>{"name"=>"Emmanuel", "email"=>"lalapnt@yahoo.com", "country"=>"Poland", "phone"=>"000000000"}, "commit"=>"I'm interested!"}
  Rendered shared/_error_messages.html.erb (1.1ms)
  Rendered investors/new.html.erb within layouts/application (7.9ms)
Completed 200 OK in 163ms (Views: 162.7ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

Comment: How did you install Foundation? Via gem, bower, or manually included?

Comment: Can you post your routes?

Comment: I think I know what @Zoran is on to...  Your logs don't indicate any `post` to the `InvestorsController`, which is what would call the `#create` method if you use RESTful routes...  I'd double-check that your routes are correct and that your form is making a `post` to the `InvestorsController`.

Comment: @Zoran posted my routes.rb ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The last part of your log file:

```
Started GET "/investors/new?utf8=%E2%9C%93&authenticity_token=qgXmHuloO7rKfYIUXFH5PVjsLDjpYcNDsX6gIff71a4n%2BEhe%2Fuu7DOt29%2B50S8B11TZp1uxaxf3%2BBqgSuHp%2B3Q%3D%3D&investor%5Bname%5D=Emmanuel&investor%5Bemail%5D=lalapnt%40yahoo.com&investor%5Bcountry%5D=Poland&investor%5Bphone%5D=000000000&commit=I%27m+interested%21" for ::1 at 2015-06-12 02:18:16 +0200
Processing by InvestorsController#new as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"qgXmHuloO7rKfYIUXFH5PVjsLDjpYcNDsX6gIff71a4n+Ehe/uu7DOt29+50S8B11TZp1uxaxf3+BqgSuHp+3Q==", "investor"=>{"name"=>"Emmanuel", "email"=>"lalapnt@yahoo.com", "country"=>"Poland", "phone"=>"000000000"}, "commit"=>"I'm interested!"}
  Rendered shared/_error_messages.html.erb (1.1ms)
  Rendered investors/new.html.erb within layouts/application (7.9ms)
Completed 200 OK in 163ms (Views: 162.7ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

It looks like you're submitting a form to /investors/new but as a GET and not a POST, thus calling the #show action of /investors/new, rather than #create at /investors/new.

The raw HTML made me look closer - you have two form tags:

```
<form div class="small-6 large-centered columns">
    <fieldset>
        <legend> Enter your best details</legend>
<%= form_for(@investor) do |f| %>
```

Change this to:

```
<div class="small-6 large-centered columns">
    <fieldset>
        <legend> Enter your best details</legend>
<%= form_for(@investor) do |f| %>
```

In fact, your entire view will need to change:

```
<div class="small-6 large-centered columns">
  <%= form_for(@investor) do |f| %>
    <fieldset>
      <legend> Enter your best details</legend>

      <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>

      <%= f.label :name %>
      <%= f.text_field :name, :placeholder => "John Doe" %> </br>

      <%= f.label :email %>
      <%= f.text_field :email, :placeholder => "you@example.com" %></br>

      <%= f.label :country %>
      <%= f.text_field :country %></br>

      <%= f.label :phone %>
      <%= f.text_field :phone, :placeholder => "+48000000000" %></br>
    </fieldset>

    <%= f.submit "I'm interested!", :class => 'button radius' %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

Comment: @siaw23 It's definitely worth checking out CDub's suggestion. I can't imagine anything inside of Foundation's installation/generator that would compromise your controller or existing views.

Comment: i posted the form code. what could be wrong with it?

Comment: On the surface, nothing I can see.  What does the actual HTML generated by the form look like?  (Just the <form> ... </form> part)

Comment: Let's continue this in chat: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80340/room-for-cdub-and-siaw23